Koszul Duality and Tensor Product of Finite Dimensional Algebras
Given a pair of finite dimensional Koszul algebras $A$ and $B$ over an algebraically closed field $k$, it is not too hard to show, abstractly, that their tensor product $A \otimes_k B$ is likewise Koszul.
However, I have not been able to find an explicit description of the Koszul dual of this tensor. I've found a few resources that make an off-hand remark that, writing $E(A)$ to denote the Koszul dual of $A$,  we have
\begin{align*}
E(A \otimes_k B) \cong E(A) \otimes_k E(B) 
\end{align*}
but I have not been able to find an explicit proof of this fact. Does anyone have a reference?

It turns out that this result as stated is slightly off: the actual statement should be that, for associative algebras $A$ and $B$ over a algebraically closed field $k$, there is an isomorphism of algebras
\begin{equation}
E(A\otimes_k B) \cong E(A) \boxtimes_k E(B) 
\end{equation}
where $- \boxtimes_k -$ denotes the skew tensor product, i.e., the algebra that has the same vector space as $A \otimes_k B$ but where multiplication is given by
\begin{equation} 
(a_1 \otimes a_2)(b_1 \otimes b_2) = (-1)^{|a_2||b_1|} a_1 b_1 \otimes a_2 b_2 
\end{equation}
The intuition behind this isomorphism is that the prototypical example of Koszul duality takes a symmetric algebra of a vector space to the exterior algebra of a vector space. Thus, morally, Koszul duality takes commutative relations to anti-commutative relations. This result is given here is Section 3: https://www.emis.de/journals/AMA/AMA01-2003/ama012003martinez.pdf
However, there are some important examples when the regular and skew tensor produce Morita equivalent algebras; if anyone has a better understanding of when this phenomenon occurs more generally, please let me know!
